# Relation between multiple variables

Tags: python

I'm using the code below to get the relation between two variables, as an example in this code, I'm looking for the relation between Drill_participation and Fire_alarm.

```py
f = lambda x : np.round(x/x.sum() * 100)
Drill_participate_Fire_alarm = df1.groupby(['Drill_participate','Fire_alarm'])['Fire_alarm'].count().unstack().apply(f, axis=1)
Drill_participate_Fire_alarm.plot(kind='bar', color=['pink', 'b','g','r','y','k','m','c','gray','olive','orange'])
plt.ylabel('# Drill_participate vs Fire_alarm')
plt.title('Drill_participate vs Fire_alarm')
plt.savefig('Drill_participate vs Fire_alarm.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))
plt.show()
```

This is the result:

[image]

I want to get the relation between one variable let's say `Drill` and multiple variables example `Firea1`, `Firea2`, `Firea3`.

So basically what i'm looking for is something like this

```py
f = lambda x : np.round(x/x.sum() * 100)
Drill_participate_Fire_alarm = df1.groupby(['Drill_participate','Fire_alarm1','Fire_alarm2','Fire_alarm3'])[Fire_alarm1','Fire_alarm2','Fire_alarm3'].count().unstack().apply(f, axis=1)
```

I have a very very basic knowledge of python and I'm just using it to analyze my data with codes available on the net.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code in your question.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have written - how does its output differ from your expected output? Can you share how the dataframe looks like?

Comment: @medium-dimensional i've edited the original post to make it more clear

Comment: Do not group by the same column that you want to count. Do something like `df1.groupby(['Drill_participate']).count()`. Not sure if this is what you want...

Comment: The "something like" is probably not what you're looking for (you wouldn't be asking otherwise). Can you show an example of how the output would look like? Not the function that you though may work, but didn't.